# What is the difference between a ABI change and non-ABI change

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, abi

In various articles and videos published by the Android team related to Gradle optimisations, I have seen build performance compared for ABI changes and non-ABI change. What does it mean and what are some examples of it, when coding in Java/Kotlin and when using native code like C++?

Reference:
[image: Image I'm referring to]
Taken from video: https://youtu.be/S_zZRBJxTQ0?t=267

Comment: When I Google for "what is ABI in programming" I get this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface

Comment: You should edit your post to include links/quotes of articles/videos of what you are confused about as the terminology used by each author/speaker may not have the same meaning.

Comment: Added reference Image and linked the video. Thanks for point it out.

Comment: The video explains this.  The first is a build change that adds a public method, and the second is a build that modifies a method body with no change to the public API.  Like literally 10 seconds after the time in the video you linked to.

Comment: You can see a more thorough explanation with examples here: https://blog.gradle.org/compilation-avoidance

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Ref/credits: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/15886#issuecomment-989999391

ABI stands for Application Binary Interface.

An ABI change is a change that modifies the ABI, iow the "public api" that downstream consumers compile against. All consumers need to be recompiled.

A non-ABI change is a change that does not modify the ABI, iow only touches the "private implementation". Consumers compilation can be skipped.